# If the string contains at least one c, then how can i print the position of the first "c"

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this problemset: If the string contains at least one c, then how can i print the position of the first "c" letter?

I only get the position 0 when I am running this code, even if the c is at an another position.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class innlev3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String i;

        i = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a word: "));

        int position = getPosition(i);

        if (i.contains("c")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The position of the letter c is: " + position);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Strengen inneholder ikke noen bokstaver med c.");
        }
    }

    private static int getPosition(String i) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `indexOf()`?

Comment: I tried indexOf(), but it didn't work with the JOptionPane.showMessage()

Answer (score 4):

Use `String#indexOf` to print the position:

```
if (i.contains("c")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The position of the letter c is: " + i.indexOf("c"));
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Strengen inneholder ikke noen bokstaver med c.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int position = i.indexOf('c');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with help of `indexOf(int ch)` method in String class

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String::indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-):

```
private static int getPosition(String i, char search) {
    return i.indexOf(search);
}
```

then to use it:

```
int position = getPosition(i, 'c');
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `getPosition` method with the below one:

```
private static int getPositionOfC(String i) {
   return i.indexOf('c');
}
```